# Add commas in amount using php

Tags: php, jquery

Please i have a jquery code to add commas in number at the right place now i don't want to use jquery for it again how do i do this using php to add commas?
bellow is my attempt

**The jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


    $("#numbal").each(function(){
    var bal_cc = $(this).html();
    bal_cc = numberWithCommas(bal_cc);

    $(this).html(bal_cc)

        })


});//]]> 

</script>
```

**PHP Tried**

```
<?php

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.str_replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
$bal = numberWithCommas($UserCradit);
echo $ubal;
?>
```

Comment: If you're attempting some kind of i18n currency formatting in PHP ... there's a class for that : http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php ... also, your syntax is off `x.str_replace` is *not* PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong: `x.str_replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");` you should learn to use [Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) before coming to stack overflow. `number_format`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is what you are looking for

```
<?php
    $bal = number_format($UserCradit);
    echo $bal;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are replacing using regular expressions, you should use

```
preg_replace()
```

This should be the code:

```
<?php

function numberWithCommas($x) {
    return preg_replace('/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g', ",", $x);
}

$bal = numberWithCommas($UserCradit);
echo $ubal;
?>
```

x.str_replace() is not how you access PHP functions. Besides, str_replace() is not used for regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Change `return x.str_replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");` 
to 
`return str_replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "," ,$x)`

`x.str_replace` is not a PHP function. For more go here: [php manual str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Might wanna slap some single-quotes around the RegEx and use preg_replace ;)